# form with ngform with save button validation not working angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have a form which is dynamically generating the fields, I am using `ng-form` for this. The form has an `ng-repeat` for input fields and the main form has a 'Save' button.

i.e when one of the input fields is dirty and has content, the save button should be **enabled** and should be **disabled** otherwise.

Here is my HTML Code :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="$parent.fSForm" novalidate ">

    <fieldset class="form-group pl-sm" ng-repeat="fs in list track by $index">
    <ng-form name="innerForm">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="fsl" ng-change="fileChanged()" ng-model="fs.path" placeholder="Add new here">
        </div>    
        </ng-form>
    </fieldset>
    <a class="prop-toggle ng-binding" href="" ng-click="addNew()">Add More</a>

</form>
</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span>
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </span>

    <span>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="fSForm.$error.fooname">Save</button>
    </span>
   </div>
```

So for my save button to be **disabled** when the form loads initially how should I go about validating that with an `ng-form` present? The save should be enabled when one of the input fields has some text in it. not sure how we can handle `ng-disabled` with `ng-form` within a form save button

Comment: Just add all the validations you need to your other HTML inputs.  For example, use the `required` attribute.

Comment: i dont think form within the form is allowed. kindly check

Comment: for dynamic elements ng-form is the way to make sure to attach the ng-model correctly. But, how can i add validation for save button

Comment: You can use scope variables  to represent your ng-form and use that scope variable to add validation in save button.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani could you please show an example?